# Flask - Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to get a hello world flask app running with Python 3.9.7.

Folder structure:
py-flask/
app.py
README.md

Content of app.py:

```
from flask import flask

app = flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello Wolford"

@app.route("/greeting/")
def greeting():
    return "Nice to see you"
```

When I am in the py-flask directory, and I try running the app, I get:
`Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised.`

I've tried `python3 -m flask run` and `flask run` neither works.

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong?
pip list if its useful:

```
Package       Version
------------- -------
cachelib      0.4.1
click         8.0.3
Flask         2.0.2
Flask-Session 0.4.0
itsdangerous  2.0.1
Jinja2        3.0.2
MarkupSafe    2.0.1
pip           21.2.3
setuptools    57.4.0
Werkzeug      2.0.2
```

Comment: ending the app.py with the line:
app.run()

and invoking python app.py

will output more usable diagnostics like a stack trace

Answer (score 8):

If your typing here is correct, the error is that the importet module is misspelled (Flask must be uppecase).
Here the correct way:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello Wolford"

@app.route("/greeting/")
def greeting():
    return "Nice to see you"
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you!!!!!

Comment: Any ideas on how to get the error message to be more verbose? As it tell you what module had the import error?

Comment: To debug this: run `python app.py` (after adding an `app.run()` at the end of app.py, if you don't already have it already wrapped in an `if __name__ == "__main__":`)

Comment: Start a python shell, and try importing `app`. `from app import create_app` `app = create_app` you'll get the error on the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

This error is also emitted when there's an error in an imported module. A good way to start debugging such errors is to directly run the file with `python` (without flask run). Do not forget to call the `app` function. Just add the following lines if you are using Flask's [Application Factory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/appfactories/) pattern.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_app().run()
```

After that run the app: `python app.py`